# CSS text-align center ignored in div inside th

Tags: css

Background: After looking up how to make a scrollable table that keeps the header row fixed whilst scrolling the remainder of the table vertically, I found a cascading stylesheet on a site called jsfiddle.net

I have made some modifications, and here is my css:

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #500;
}

section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:25px;
  width:750px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}

div.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 0px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:98%;
}

td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}

td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

th {
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5px; 
  margin: auto;
/*  margin-left: -5px; */
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 2px solid #F88;
}

div.secondrow{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5px; 
  margin: auto;
/*  margin-left: -5px; */
  text-align: center;
  top: 25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 2px solid #F88;
}

th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

It works as follows in the HTML:

```
<section id="mySection" class="">
    <div id="myDiv" class="container">
        <table id="myTable"></table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Note that the height is set to 0 in the stylesheet and the data is filled in by javascript at which point it sets the height of the table to an appropriate size. (800px).

The commented out margin of -5px means also that the borders in the header are slightly to the right of that in the table. But I did auto as a suggestion in another answer.

However it still doesn't work. I had to put an &nbsp into the header names too so they don't squash up to the border. (I removed the left-padding because I want center-align).

One thing I should point out is that the visible text is not actually in the  part but inside a nested .

So the actual HTML at this point looks something like:

```
<th><div class="secondrow">&nbsp;Prev</div></th>
```

Comment: Can you make a working example? Also applying `position: absolute` to the `div` inside the `th` means that `text-align: center` won't work.

Comment: I guessed the position: absolute is essential to stop it scrolling with the rest of the table. Let me see what happens if I take that out.

Comment: I tried several other position attributes: sticky, static etc. The align works but the scrolling doesn't and it just scrolls with the table. So what should I use?

Comment: No you have to use `position: absolute`, but you have to find another way to centrally align the elements inside. And I cannot say exactly what to use until I see it working. :)

Comment: Well this is the site from which I got the stylesheet. Mine is more complex in that my header is 2 rows with some spanning 3 columns

https://jsfiddle.net/rdv1u450/

Comment: Wow man, that structure is a disaster for a frozen row. Wait, I will build you one.

Comment: The one you built me does not work properly. You either have to fix all the columns to the same width or the header doesn't match across with the data. The other one does work like that, and I could manually pad the column names to look central. I was hoping to come back today and find a solution close to yours that allows the columns to not get fixed width but there is no further action on here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, check the edited answer. Now the header will always match across with the data irrespective of the content inside.

Comment: I do not see a change. I see you are still doing minwidth=120. I don't want that. I don't mind a small minwidth but I want to see variable length columns with the header rows matching those of the body

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest change the structure of your table completely.

There are many things wrong in the stylesheet:

- There is absolutely no reason to have a `div` inside a `th`.
- The height of the `thead`, `th` & `th` for the frozen row is zero and the `div`s have been manipulated to keept it constant which is essentially a bad idea.
- The parent `section` of the table has been given `padding` to provide background to the top row divs which is as bad as it gets for a table structure.

The entire purpose of using a table here is destroyed using a structure like that.

For better table structure idea, please go through the [MDN Table article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) to know more about the best practices.

I found a better table structure with a frozen row. Please go through it for better idea.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/esu0m57q/3/

Refer code:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/

thead {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

tbody {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 40px;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  background-color: #99a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Macelsfield</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny Jones</td>
        <td>Threlkeld</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Frampton</td>
        <td>Avebury</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Simon King</td>
        <td>Malvern</td>
        <td>Worchestershire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
        <td>St Albans</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>Lothian</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
        <td>Bedford</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kat Dibble</td>
        <td>Manhattan</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
        <td>Alderley</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried much of what was there and the column widths do not then adjust to the data when there is overflow in the cells.

Comment: Having a frozen header and matching it with the table body without a fixed width is tricky. However I have come up with a solution that might work. Check edited answer and let me know.

Comment: Your solution doesn't even work on jsfiddle.

I ended up solving it with Javascript that loops through the columns in the first <tbody<<td> element and sets the widths to the 2nd row of the header (as the first has colspan=3). You also need to check padding or adjust to it. To do it properly you then need to check the actual header width which might be bigger if the text doesn't fit or wrap in it, and then set the body one back to that if greater.

Comment: There was a height issue on jsfiddle. Check update fiddle and it does work. Also, P.S. usage of Javascript for alignment on tables is generally discouraged. :)

Comment: Well maybe CSS4 will fix it without the need. At present I see no alternative. Yours didn't work and relies on width:100% on all the cells which seems to just make them all the same size. So when I put data in one of the cells that went past the boundary and it couldn't wrap, it overran to the next cell, while Age remained as wide as all the others even though it doesn't need so much space.